# TV series about aliens that hook up to an energy source called 'The White'

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

As far as I know this was around 2012. I thought the show was named *THE WHITE*, but haven't found anything on it. Also, I have only found one other person who remembers this show, which as far as I know only aired one episode. The aliens in it looked human, but had suction cups on their forearms and would stand in pods and 'plug into' an energy source called "The White".

Comment: Obvious nasty sarcastic pun elided.

Comment: What channel did you see this show on, and in which country? And can you tell us anything else about the show? Like were there humans in the show? Was it set wholly or partly on Earth? And were the aliens antagonistic or benign?

Answer (score 9):

In *Star Trek: DS9*, the jem'hadar were addicted to a substance called ketracel-white, which was sometimes referred to just as "the white".

Comment: The Jem'Hadar tubes were inserted right above their left collarbone, nothing on their forearms. Also DS9 had like 130 episodes or something.

Comment: @Derek If you weren't a big DS9 fan and then tuned into one of the jem'hadar / vorta centric episodes, you might think to yourself, "Wow, what is this new show?"